# Difference between GEOSERVER.war and GEOSERVER.exe?

Tags: geoserver, installation, tomcat

Can someone comment on the performance/usage differences and advantages between deploying GeoServer from a web archive or installing GeoServer with the Windows installer?

I currently have GeoServer deployed in Apache Tomcat is this necessary to install another (GeoServer with the Windows installer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geoserver.exe` installs GeoServer as a windows service (or optionally as a manually started program) running inside Jetty. `geoserver.war` is a platform independant war file that needs to be installed into a container server (e.g. tomcat, jboss, jetty etc).

The downside of using the exe installer is that you have to be on a windows machine, you also get less choice of servlet container.